# image picker preselect item on initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using image-picker from http://rvera.github.io/image-picker/ and I would like to preselect an image during the page load. I've tried this:

```
$('#image_picker option[value="54fdada12476"]').prop('selected',true);

  $("#image_picker").imagepicker(...
```

But doesn't work. Also tried selected option for image-picker and jquery attr(). Is there an easy way to select by value?

Regards,

Comment: Add `selected=selected` attribute if it works

Comment: No, this solution doesn't work: $('#image_picker option[value="54fdada12476"]').attr('selected','selected');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, got it:

```
 $("#image_picker").find('option[value="54fdada12476"]').prop('selected',true);
```

this selects the desired option

Answer (score 0):

and add

```
 $("#image_picker").imagepicker();
```

after `$("#image_picker").find('option[value="54fdada12476"]').prop('selected',true);`

to reinitilize the picker